# Automatic launch of a program as root on debian 10 boot

Tags: debian, snmp, boot

On a PC with debian 10 I have developed a C program (my own snmp agent) that can be found in:

```
/home/myuser/myapp/myprogram
```

And I need it to start automatically every time the PC boots, running as root.

To do this I follow the following steps:

1. I create the file "/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service" with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. I create the file "/etc/rc.local" with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

/home/myuser/myapp/myprogram

exit 0
```

3. Set the permissions to rc.local:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

4. Enable the service to start during boot

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

5. When I start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start rc-local
```

I get these errors on the screen:

```
Job for rc-local.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rc-local.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

6. When I check the status of the service, it shows an error:

```
systemctl status rc-local

● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-11-16 12:29:59 CET; 3min 36s ago
  Process: 1686 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=139)

Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local...
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test rc.local[1686]: Modules initializing
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test rc.local[1686]: duplicate registration: MIB modules trapInfo and trapInf
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test rc.local[1686]: Segmentation fault
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=139
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 12:29:59 i66vm-test systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local.
```

I do not understand why it does not start, since if I manually launch the program, it does start and works right, even if it shows the advertisement:

```
duplicate registration: MIB modules trapInfo and trapInfo (oid .1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.1.1.2.1).
```

Any help is appreciated.

There is a better way to launch a program automatically in debian 10 during computer boot,
considering that it must be run as root?

Answer (score 0):

as you asked for another way, yes there are several. The simplest way is to enter a line in the roots `crontab -e`

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /home/myuser/myapp/myprogram
```